# Can Cordova/Phonegap app be started without invoking UI

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am wondering if its possible to start a Cordova App without invoking any UI to the screen, so the app starts in the background?

If there are any plugin that does that?

I am trying to figure if it is possible so then a push notification can start up the app in the background without bringing it to the foreground everything.

Answer (score 1):

you can see this cordova plugin :

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-background-app

works on ios and android

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look